# "Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)"

Tags: java, android

Whenver I try and run the app it crashes with error. Below is the error logcat while crash.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process
>   C:\Users\ahsan.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar\5e954ff0b6f280675155312adb7d7dad\jars\classes.jar
>
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while
>   dexing.
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/android/tools/r8/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList$ReverseImmutableList 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.android.tools.r8.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$ReverseImmutableList 
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: have you added compile options for java 8 in build gradle?

Comment: yes, I added complieOptions in gradle but still giving me errors.   compileOptions {
            setSourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
            setTargetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
        }
now, what can I do?

Comment: As far as I can see this is not logcat output, but compilation output. To me it looks like you have some jars which are corrupted. Have you tried to clean your gradle cache?

Comment: thanks for your reply :) my issue is solved now thanku

Answer (score 0):

i tried everything, All the possible solution which are available on StackOver flow.
 but I didn't get the solution but at last, I resolve this issue by using

> classpath' com.android.tools:r8:1.2.52'

add this classpath into build.gradle(project:YourApp) then sync the project this resolve my problem :)